# Как пишется слово "НЕИСПОЛЬЗУЕМАЯ" в следующем примере:

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

как пишется слово "НЕИСПОЛЬЗУЕМАЯ" в следующем примере: "Недвижимость, не используемая / неиспользуемая в основной деятельности" и ПОЧЕМУ?

Answer (score 1):

*Не используемая*. Не с причастием при наличии зависимых слов пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Недвижимость, не используемая в основной деятельности.

Пояснение.

1. Как верно было указано,  слова на МЫЙ являются причастиями только в том случае, если они образованы от переходных глаголов совершенного вида (это здесь соблюдается) и при наличии зависимого слова в Т.п. Зависимого слова нет, следовательно, это прилагательное. Получается, что "НЕ" надо писать слитно?
2. Но мы всё-таки выбираем раздельную форму написания, но в соответствии с другим правилом: НЕ  пишется раздельно с ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫМИ, имеющими пояснительные слова, без которых  прилагательные не употребляются (в этом случае НЕ относится к словосочетанию, а не к одному слову):готовый к выходу актер — не готовый к выходу актер, свойственный ему стиль — не свойственный ему стиль.
3. Примеры: "Григорий и в себе радостно ощущал эту не свойственную ему за последние годы податливость на смех". "Не склонный к полуправдам, могу сказать: нет скорби о потерянном, нет страха перед смертью во Вселенной".

Comment: у Лопатина и Розенталя в правилах на -мый нет такого "другого правила": НЕ пишется раздельно с ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫМИ, имеющими пояснительные слова, без которых прилагательные не употребляются (в этом случае НЕ относится к словосочетанию, а не к одному слову):готовый к выходу актер – не готовый к выходу актер, свойственный ему стиль – не свойственный ему стиль.

Comment: 1.У Розенталя есть указание для ОБОСОБЛЕННЫХ оборотов на основе прилагательного, в этом случае прилагательное по значению приближается к причастию и, соответственно, написание раздельное:"Недвижимость, не используемая  в основной деятельности"
2. О том, что "НЕ" может относиться к словосочетанию, говорит Кайдалова в "Современной русской орфографии" (1998). Например, "не склонный, не готовый к чему-либо" пишутся всегда раздельно. Еще пример: "Она была бледна, но не (болезненно бледна)".

Comment: 2. А вот со словом "НЕСВОЙСТВЕННЫЙ" не очень ясная картина. В словарях и учебниках дается слитное написание, но интересно то, что прилагательное без зависимых слов вообще не употребляется (а в словаре определяется следующим образом: несвойственный - не присущий). Розенталь говорит о раздельном написании только при обособлении, но в то же время при значительном распространении оборота встречается его раздельное написание и в необособленном виде.

Answer (score 0):

Да, раздельно. А также при отрицании и противопоставлении.

Answer (score 0):

Следует различать написание не со словами на -мый, образованными от переходных глаголов несовершенного вида: такие слова могут быть как страдательными причастиями настоящего времени, так и прилагательными (в первом случае написание с не раздельное, во втором — слитное). Причастиями они являются, если при них в качестве пояснительного слова употребляется творительный падеж действующего лица, реже творительный орудия (так называемый инструментальный); при наличии других пояснительных слов они становятся прилагательными (теряют значение страдательности и значение времени и приобретают качественное значение). Ср.: не любимый матерью ребенок — нелюбимые в детстве игры (во втором случае слово нелюбимый указывает на постоянный признак, обозначает примерно то же, что «неприятный», «нежелательный»); движение, не тормозимое воздухом — невидимая с Земли сторона Луны.

Так что: неиспользуемая в основной деятельности. Но: не используемая ею в основной деятельности.